# unable to fetch json from String

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have this JSON String:

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "formal",
      "price": "999"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "sports",
      "price": "799"
    }
  ]
}
```

JAVA Code

```
try {
    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(result);
    dataArray = parentObject.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i < dataArray.length();i++) {
        JSONObject finalObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
        price[i] = String.valueOf(finalObject.getInt(TAG_PRICE));
        type[i] = finalObject.getString(TAG_TYPE);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can't seem to be able to get data, is there something wrong?

Comment: What error you get? Also post your full code (TAG_ARRAY, TAG_PRICE, TAG_TYPE... values).

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please post your logcat and the full code.

Comment: What are TAG_ARRAY, TAG_PRICE, TAG_TYPE? Where did you initialized price[] and type[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. Here i used [json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/downloads) as JSON library.

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\sample.json"));

        String result = jsonObject.toString();
        System.out.println(result);

        JSONObject resJsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(result);

        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Data");


        for( int i =0; i<jsonArray.size(); i++){
            JSONObject childJson = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            price[i] = (String) childJson.get("price");
            type[i] = (String) childJson.get("type");
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(price));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(type));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
       try {
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(result);

            dataArray = parentObject.optJSONArray("Data");
            int i=0;
            for(i=0;i < dataArray.length();i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                price[i] = String.valueOf(finalObject.getInt(TAG_PRICE));
                type[i] = finalObject.getString(TAG_TYPE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If you interract a lot with JSON, consider using [gson](http://github.com/google/gson) or other dedicated json serialization libraries